# how to set editBox focus after panel/page refresh

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

On my xPage I have just a panel and editBox inside.

```
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onkeydown" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panel1">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:inputText>
</xp:panel>
```

by pressing Enter key in editBox I want to refresh my panel1 and then return focus to my edit box inputText1.

P.S. it's supposed there are other components on that panel this is why I want to refresh it once user enter something into editbox and press Enter key. Any focus() set code doesn't work once you refresh the panel either into onkeydown event or in onComplete of eventhandler. But you can set the focus if you ouside of that panel (e.g. new button with onclick event "...focus())"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the enter key is a normal function to receive via a JavaScript listener. Triggering a partial refresh can also be done from JavaScript via the client-side XSP object. Here's how a basic implementation would look.

```xml
    <xp:panel
        id="panel1">
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputText1">
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onkeydown"
                submit="false"
                id="eventHandler1"
                execMode="partial">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[if(event.keyCode == 13){
    event.preventDefault();
    XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panel1}",{
      onComplete: function(){
          document.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").focus();
      }
});
}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>
```

Edit:
I forgot to use `event.preventDefault()` on the enter action. I confirmed this as working in a sample XPage, shown here. Alternatively, in place of the [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) call, you could use a [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) to highlight existing text, or do [something else to put the cursor at the end of the field](http://davidwalsh.name/caret-end).
[image: focus call with partialRefresh on Enter]

Comment: Nice, Eric. I will delete my answer which only solves half of the question :-)

Comment: You had good timing, I saw yours come in just before I hit save :-P

Comment: Sorry guys, but its still doesn't work.. Still loose focus after typing a text and pressing Enter key...

 <xp:panel id="panel1">
  <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
   <xp:eventHandler event="onkeydown" submit="false"
    id="eventHandler1">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[if(event.keyCode == 13){
         XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panel1}",{
           onComplete: function(){dojo.byId("#{id:inputText1}").focus();}
         });
     }]]></xp:this.script>
   </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:inputText>
 </xp:panel>

Comment: The issues seems to be with the _onComplete_ call to _focus_ the input field. I'll update it as soon as I copy out some of my working code.

Comment: @VladP I updated my answer with what worked for me. I forgot to use the [_preventDefault_ call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on my event handling, as my XPages form was treating it as a form submission on Enter, until I captured it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [general purpose snippet](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/09/xpages-workaround-for-fields-losing.html) a while back that tries to counteract the effect of partial refresh on focus states. If I understand your issue correctly, this would remove the need to "hard code" which field you want to have focus after the refresh. You will also need the snippet for [hijacking partial refreshes](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/01/xpages-hijackingpublishing-partial.html).

I think the only thing you need to to to the field after you've added the two snippets is to make sure that the event handler/partial refresh only fires on the enter key.

In client script: **return ( thisEvent.keyCode === 13 );**

Code snippet for hijacking partial refreshes:

```
function hijackAndPublishPartialRefresh(){
 // Hijack the partial refresh
 XSP._inheritedPartialRefresh = XSP._partialRefresh;
 XSP._partialRefresh = function( method, form, refreshId, options ){  
     // Publish init
     dojo.publish( 'partialrefresh-init', [ method, form, refreshId, options ]);
     this._inheritedPartialRefresh( method, form, refreshId, options );
 }

 // Publish start, complete and error states 
 dojo.subscribe( 'partialrefresh-init', function( method, form, refreshId, options ){

  if( options ){ // Store original event handlers
   var eventOnStart = options.onStart; 
   var eventOnComplete = options.onComplete;
   var eventOnError = options.onError;
  }

  options = options || {};  
  options.onStart = function(){
   dojo.publish( 'partialrefresh-start', [ method, form, refreshId, options ]);
   if( eventOnStart ){
    if( typeof eventOnStart === 'string' ){
     eval( eventOnStart );
    } else {
     eventOnStart();
    }
   }
  };

  options.onComplete = function(){
   dojo.publish( 'partialrefresh-complete', [ method, form, refreshId, options ]);
   if( eventOnComplete ){
    if( typeof eventOnComplete === 'string' ){
     eval( eventOnComplete );
    } else {
     eventOnComplete();
    }
   }
  };

  options.onError = function(){
   dojo.publish( 'partialrefresh-error', [ method, form, refreshId, options ]);
   if( eventOnError ){
    if( typeof eventOnError === 'string' ){
     eval( eventOnError );
    } else {
     eventOnError();
    }
   }
  };
 });
}
```

Code snippet for remembering focus states:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
dojo.subscribe( 'partialrefresh-init', function(){
 // setTimeout needed to make it work in Firefox
 setTimeout(function(){
  var activeElementId = document.activeElement.id;  

  var focusSubscription = dojo.subscribe( 'partialrefresh-complete', function(){
 // Only set focus if field hasn't been overwritten/lost focus
 if( document.activeElement.id !== activeElementId ){
  var activeElement = dojo.byId(activeElementId);

  if( activeElement && /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/.test( activeElement.nodeName ) ){
   // Set focus to element/select text
   activeElement.focus();
   if( activeElement.nodeName !== 'SELECT' ){
    activeElement.select();
   }
  }
 }

   // Unsubscribe after focus attempt is done
   dojo.unsubscribe( focusSubscription );
  });

  // In case of error -> remove subscription
  var errorSubscription = dojo.subscribe( 'partialrefresh-error', function(){
     dojo.unsubscribe( focusSubscription );
  });
 }, 0 );
} );
});
```